# How to PreStore Active Directory Profiles

Tags: windows, active-directory, user-profiles

As commonly known, on a Windows computer connected to a domain, when a user logs into a workstation their profile is stored on the local machine in case connectivity to all domain controllers is lost (temporary user profile I believe). Is there a way to store a profile on a workstation without having to first login to their profile (assuming that I still have connectivity to a domain controller). I have a client that has a "field laptop". This client would like to be able to store the profile on the computer so that new users that are predownloaded to the laptop don't have to connect to a VPN first (in the case where internet connectivity isn't available).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone finds an answer, the correct answer (I believe) is that there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the rights to the network share, there's nothing to stop you making a copy of the network stored profile to the "C:\Documents and Settings" folder on any particular laptop they're going to log on to. Ensure the folder name on the laptop is the login ID and that the user has at least modify rights to it.

However, for a user that's never logged on before, I'm not sure if this will work. As I understand it, the network profile copy is created *after* the first login.

Comment: Something also tells me that this won't help with the registry side. Based on many different internet resources, Windows looks to the registry for the user's location in C:\Users (normally)